# I can't show incoming data in my Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel-8, algolia

I have a Laravel 8 project. In this project, I wanted to pull the `creators profile page` from `Algolia`. That's why I `integrated Algolia` into the project. However, previously this creator profile pages worked in a different way. Then I integrated Algolia and started getting some errors `because the names of the parts coming from Algolia and the parts coming from the old system differ`. I started to fix these parts, but no matter what I did in one part, I couldn't handle it. I don't understand what mistake I am making because everything seems to be correct.

[image]
[image]

**CreatorController**

```
    public function show($username)
    {
        $client = SearchClient::create(
            env('ALGOLIA_APP_ID'), 
            env('ALGOLIA_SECRET'),
        );

        $indexUsers = $client->initIndex("users");

        $creatorData = $indexUsers->search($username);
        $creator = $creatorData["hits"][0] ?? null;
        if(count($creatorData["hits"]) == 0 || !isset($creator)){
            abort(404);
        }

        $indexContent = $client->initIndex("courses");

        $contentData = $indexContent->search($username);
        $contents = $contentData["hits"] ?? [];
        if(count($contentData["hits"]) == 0 || !isset($contents)){
            abort(404);
        } 

        

        return view('creators.show',[
            'creator' => (object)$creator,
            'contents' => $contents,
        ]);
    }
```

**OLD show.blade.php - content section**

```
@if($creator->contents->isNotEmpty())
        <div class="bg-pippin p-8 rounded-lg">
            <h4 class="text-2xl leading-8 font-semibold mb-8">Courses from the Author </h4>
            <div class="space-y-8">
                @foreach($creator->contents as $content)
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between flex-col md:flex-row space-x-8">
                        @if($content->cover!=null)
                            <div class="w-full md:w-3/12 lg:w-2/6 mb-4 lg:mb-0">
                                <img src="{{ $content->cover }}" alt="{{ $content->name }}">
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="w-full md:w-9/12  lg:w-4/6">
                            <a href="/content/{{ $content->getUrl() }}"><h3 class="font-argent text-4xl font-bold mb-6">{{ $content->name }}</h3></a>
                            @foreach($content->categories as $category)
                                <div class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 rounded bg-soft-text mb-5">
                                    <img src="https://app.omnicourse.io/{{ $category->icon}}" alt="">
                                    <span class="text-base leading-6 font-normal text-white ml-2">{{ $category->name }}</span>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach

                            <div class="flex items-center space-x-6">
                                <div class="flex items-center">
                                    <img src="/assets/images/icon-clock-black.svg" alt="">
                                    <span  class="text-sm md:text-base leading-6 font-normal ml-1">{{ $content->getLengthHours() }} hrs</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex items-center">
                                    <img src="/assets/images/icon-list-black.svg" alt="">
                                    <span  class="text-sm md:text-base leading-6 font-normal ml-1">{{ count($content->lectures) }} Lessons</span>
                                </div>
                                <!--div class="flex items-center">
                                    <img src="/assets/images/icon-like-black.svg" alt="">
                                    <span  class="text-sm md:text-base leading-6 font-normal ml-1">96%</span>
                                </div -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
             </div>
        </div>
        @endif
```

**NEW show.blade.php - content section**

```
        @if(count($contents) > 0)
        <div class="bg-pippin p-8 rounded-lg">
            <h4 class="text-2xl leading-8 font-semibold mb-8">Courses from the Author </h4>
            <div class="space-y-8">
                @foreach($contents as $content)
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between flex-col md:flex-row space-x-8">
                        @if($content['cover']!=null)
                            <div class="w-full md:w-3/12 lg:w-2/6 mb-4 lg:mb-0">
                                <img src="{{ $content['cover'] }}" alt="{{ $content['name'] }}">
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="w-full md:w-9/12  lg:w-4/6">
                            {{-- <a href="/content/{{ $content->getUrl() }}"><h3 class="font-argent text-4xl font-bold mb-6">{{ $content->name }}</h3></a> --}}
                            
                            @foreach($contents as $categorys)
                                <div class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 rounded bg-soft-text mb-5">
                                    <img src="https://app.omnicourse.io/{{ $categorys['icon'] }}" alt="">
                                    <span class="text-base leading-6 font-normal text-white ml-2">{{ $category['name'] }}</span>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach

                            <div class="flex items-center space-x-6">
                                <div class="flex items-center">
                                    <img src="/assets/images/icon-clock-black.svg" alt="">
                                    <span  class="text-sm md:text-base leading-6 font-normal ml-1">{{ $content->getLengthHours() }} hrs</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex items-center">
                                    <img src="/assets/images/icon-list-black.svg" alt="">
                                    <span  class="text-sm md:text-base leading-6 font-normal ml-1">{{ count($content->lectures) }} Lessons</span>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
             </div>
        </div>
        @endif
```

**Data from Algolia and their names**

```
{
  "id": 114,
  "user_id": 741,
  "isLearnBite": 0,
  "name": "Funding Your Business",
  "cover": "https://omnicoursewebsites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/courses/114/images/cover/769312_1643628130.jpg",
  "color": "#fefefe",
  "description": "Funding Your Business",
  "short_description": "Funding Your Business",
  "length": 5293,
  "order": 0,
  "status_id": 1,
  "created_at": "2022-01-28T09:19:31.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2022-01-31T11:22:22.000000Z",
  "custom_fields": {
    "dynamic_link": "https://omnicourse.page.link/cQgs9TcoPen1J6dZ8"
  },
  "lectures_count": 22,
  "lecturer_name": "Adam Shaw",
  "lecturer_username": "adamshaw",
  "lecturer_avatar": "https://omnicoursewebsites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/creator_thumbnail/741/2022-03-29/thumbnail_400X400_565720_1640103825.jpg",
  "tags": [
    1,
    30,
    43,
    73
  ],
  "categories": [
    2
  ],
  "last_listened_data": null,
  "user_rating": 0,
  "isFavorited": false,
  "isBookMarked": false,
  "isCompleted": false,
  "creator_profile": {
    "name": "Adam Shaw",
    "username": "adamshaw",
    "avatar": "https://omnicoursewebsites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/creator_thumbnail/741/2022-03-29/thumbnail_400X400_565720_1640103825.jpg",
    "about": "What is important in life?\r\n\r\nI have asked myself this question for as long as I can remember. My path has been varied and fun, which for me is what makes life good.\r\n\r\nMy key expertise is working with energy and mind-body medicine. I also have a more recent background in funding and business consultancy.\r\n\r\nFor 13 years I worked as a nurse, developing key skills and awareness in counselling the dying and their families. Through discussing what was important in life with thousands of people close to death, I noticed certain patterns amongst the regrets and achievements of those close to death. \r\n\r\nIt also led me to discovering energy medicine through Reiki, Vortex Healing and Energetic NLP. This, in turn, led to a path into Mind-Body medicine.\r\n\r\nWhat does all of that mean for you though?\r\n\r\nIf you want to use your mind to improve your wellbeing, I can help. \r\n\r\nIf you are questioning your purpose on the planet, I can facilitate that journey.\r\n\r\nIf you are a company owner looking for help with funding, I can point you in the right direction.",
    "custom_fields": {
      "youtube": "https://www.youtube.com/c/AdamShawTheHeartGuy",
      "linkedin": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/adamshawtheheartguy/",
      "instagram": "https://www.instagram.com/the_heart_guy_/",
      "twitter": "https://twitter.com/adam_shaw",
      "website": "adamshaw.co",
      "email_octopus_id": "ce1b2106-69ec-11ec-96e5-06b4694bee2a",
      "email_octopus_last_update": "2022-03-26 00:46:46",
      "avatar_thumb_400*400": "https://omnicoursewebsites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/creator_thumbnail/741/2022-03-29/thumbnail_400X400_565720_1640103825.jpg"
    }
  },
  "_tags": [
    "App\\Course::114"
  ],
  "objectID": "App\\Course::114"
}
```

Comment: You're doing `@foreach($contents as $content)`, then a few lines later `@foreach($contents as $categorys)` instead of `@foreach($content->categories as $category)` that you were getting in your original blade. Then `categories` in your object is just an array of numbers instead of the actual category relationship. The first is an easy fix, the second, you're going to have to figure out how to get the child category for the contents

Comment: @aynber So now this part `@foreach($contents as $categorys)` , should i change it like this `@foreach($content->categories as $category)`

Comment: Yes, just like you had in the original blade

Comment: @aynber When I changed it it started giving an error like this: `Attempt to read property "categories" on array (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs:omnicourse_web_frontend/resources/views/creators/show.blade.php) ` Is that the second part you're talking about?

Comment: Apparently `$content` is an array, not an object. So `@foreach($content['categories'] as $category)`. The second part I was talking about is that categories is an array of numbers instead of an array of category object/arrays, so `$category` will be `2`